# How can I reset the height of scrollbar in listview in QML

Tags: qt, qml

I have create a listview with a custom scroll bar. In listview the image of scroll will be **resized** by the list container. The height of the scrollbar will be changed **depend on the size of list data**. In my case **I want to show the original image** which the height of the srollbar haven't be changed. Then print out the height data. Here is my code,

```
ScrollBar　{
    id: bar       
    implicitHeight: 780 //the size of the original image
    implicitWidth: 33
    contentItem: Image {
        id: sb
        source:"1.png"
    }       
}
Keys.onPressed: { console.log(bar.implicitWidth)}
```

I use the **implicitHeight** to reset the height. It can change the height. **However**, when I set it to 780(the height of the original image), the result show that the height is 560(the height depend on list data). I need to set implicitHeight to the value bigger than 780(like 1000, I don't know how to calculate the accurate value). Then the result of height will be showed to 780.Why?

Then I tried this code,

```
ScrollBar　{
    id: ba     
    Component.onCompleted: console.log(bar.size)
    contentItem:
        Rectangle {
        implicitWidth: 780
        implicitHeight: 33
        Image {
        id: scrollBar
        source:"1.png"
        }
    }
}
```

This time, the result show the height of 780! However, I **cannot use id to access** the implicitHeight, I don't know how to print out the height.

So,my **questions** are

1. What's the different between two cases? Why the height is not accurate in first case?
2. If I use second method, how can I access(change) the height data by keyboard?

Comment: why c+++????????

Comment: As i am studying qml,i don't want to use C++.

Comment: So why do you use that tag in your question?

Comment: What are tags, and how should I use them?:https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: why c???????????

Comment: The first difference is: In the first example you have `id: bar` in the second `id: ba` - so there is no `id: bar` which you could access.

Comment: In the second example, you have a `Rectangle` which will be resized, and it contains a `Image` which is totally not affected by that, thus staying at **its** `implicitWidth/Height`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `ScrollBar` the `contentItem` is automatically resized relatively to the range it needs to manage on its length. If it is a horizontal scroll bar, it will take the `implicitHeight` to be the `height` of the contentItem, and change the width, and for vertical scroll bars, the other way around.

In your example, that is the same. The `height` of your `contentItem` will change in both cases.
But since your `Image` is not sized depending on its parent, in the second case, it wont care for any resizing of that parent, and stay at its implicit width and height.

Maybe this example helps you understanding the relations:

```
Button {
    id: b2
    width: parent.width / 2 - 5
    height: 50
    onClicked: lv.model++
    text: 'add data'
}

Button {
    id: b1
    width: parent.width / 2 -5
    x: parent.width / 2 + 5
    height: 50
    onClicked: value += 30
    property int value: 30
    text: 'change width of the red bobbl.'
}

ListView {
    id: lv
    model: 5
    anchors.fill: parent
    anchors.topMargin: 50
    spacing: 5
    delegate: Rectangle {
        width: parent.width
        height: 40
        border.color: 'red'
    }
    ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
        id: bar
        policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
        contentItem: Rectangle {
            id: thisWillBeAutomaticallyResizedNoMatterWhatYouDo
            implicitWidth: 6
            radius: width / 2
            color: 'blue'
            onHeightChanged: console.log("Height changed:", height, thisCouldBeYourImage.width, thisCouldBeYourImage.height)

            Rectangle {
                id: thisWillChangeTheSizeWithTheIndicator
                color: 'yellow'
                opacity: 0.7
                width: height
                height: parent.height
                radius: height / 2
                anchors.centerIn: parent
            }

            Rectangle {
                id: thisCouldBeYourImage
                width: b1.value % 200
                height: width
                radius: width / 2
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                color: 'red'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! In my first example, how can i calculate the implicitHeight of the bar(if i want to show the image height). I tried "780 * (2 - bar.size)" ,but it not the right result. 780*bar.size is the AutomaticallyResized height ,right. So if i set 780 * (2 - bar.size) to the bar, it would show the height to 780,but didn't. Why

Comment: Also, does any method to access parameters of contentItem from outside. I want to update the parameters from outside.

Comment: Sure. Just address it via the `id`. E.g. instead of `onClicked: value += 30`  you could also write: `onClicked: thisCouldBeYourImage.width = thisCouldBeYourImage.width + 30 % 200`

Comment: Your first comment I do not understand. What do you try to achive?

Comment: I want to use my first example to show the original image height. As you said,contentItem will be automatically resized no matter what i do. I found that if i change the height of contentItem 's parent. The image height will be changed. So i want to calculate the height of the parent to resize the image height firstly(set the height bigger than original ) and after automatically resized(height will be set to smaller) the image height will be the original image height

Comment: Can i ask one more question? As implicitHeight can not be set in image. I tried to use height instead. However the height have be changed no mater what value i set.Why?

Comment: If it is the *root element* in your *contentItem* that is what happens. If it is not the *root element* in your *contentItem* it won't happen. It is good that it happens to the *contentItem*. You can use `onHeightChanged: height = mydesiredheight` in the root element of your content item. I think you won't like the result. The image will be of your desired height, though.

Comment: Thank you very much.I solve my problem by using Component.onComplete to set the width after instance! But now i have another , if u have time,can you take a look?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49485981/how-can-i-change-the-speed-of-listview-scrolling-in-qml