# How can i change the speed of listview scrolling in QML?

Tags: qt, qml, scrollbar

I have created a list by using listview in QML. In my case, i want to change the speed of the **list scrolling, scrollBar and the highlight** to **different** value. For example,

[image]

Here is a list. While i move the highlight to the next element, **three** types of animation will be happened.

1. scrollBar will scroll to bottom
2. list will scroll to the top
3. highlight will scroll to the next element

As i known, i can change the the highlight by

```
ListView {
   highlightMoveDuration : 200
}
```

I found that three types animations will **start at the same time and last for the same time**.

But in my case, i want to set three animations to stop at different time.
For example:

1. ScrollBar: start:0, End:300
2. List: start:0, End:400
3. highlight: start:0, End:200

How can i do that. Also, if they **start at the different time**, how can i do that?

Comment: ScrollBar and ListView are syncronized. They are not animated seperatly. If you want to do that, create a detached instance of the ScrollBar and place it however you like.

Comment: Thank you very much! How about highlight ? highlight ,ScrollBar and ListView are syncronized? or just ScrollBar and ListView ?

Comment: You can just not set `highlightFollowsCurrentItem`, than you can take care for positioning the highlight as you like.

Comment: Yes, i tried it. I set it to false and set it in listview. At that time i can change the speed of the highlight.But i found that if i change the speed, the speed of the list and scrollbar also will be changed.So i wonder  whether highlight ,ScrollBar and ListView are syncronized or not.